Cat biting new cat
My resident male cat is 9 months old and was separated from his brother around 10 weeks. Since then he hasn't been around other cats.
My new cat is female and 10 months old. She has been around other cats so is confident and walks around tail high and is very chill. Normal slow introductions were done, however, my resident cat doesn't seem to understand how to interact.
He stalks her while she plays or walks around. Instead of licking, he always just tries biting her neck. Even when she is licking him, he just bites instead and never licks. Is this a dominance or mating thing? Will it stop? How can I teach him to lick instead?

is any of the cats spayed or neutered?

You do not specify whether the cats are neutered/spayed. I'm hoping they are, but the behaviours you described make me suspicious they are not.
They are probably both sexual and dominance behaviours. It is not uncommon during mating for the male to bite the female cat's neck. At this age it would be very likely that she becomes pregnant soon, if not already.
Spaying and neutering would likely help to reduce the behaviour. No amount of you trying to train or teach him will override his sexual instincts.

Just for what it's worth, with my two (both neutered), Harry would often lick Hazel's face before settling down to cuddle with her... But he'd also sometimes grab her by the scruff of the neck for a few seconds. Note grab, not nip or bite. I suspect he had some vague instinct that there was something he was supposed to do with a female but neither of them was equipped to send or receive the right signals. It may also have had dominance or play aspects -- "I'm the boss!" "Yeah, right, guy. Keep telling yourself that, if it makes you happy. I'm going back to sleep."
